# how to minimize jquery further when using very few of jquery functions like one or two

Tags: jquery

I use jquery in my code just for fadein and fadeout. The latest version. The minimised version is 74 kb. is it possible to further minimize jquery because i use just two functions only and for that i thought not to load a 74kb of javascript code. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure your server to gzip it, but I don't think that would make it very much smaller. Do use the CDN however, it will be much faster than serving from your own server, in most circumstances.

You could also configure your server to send out far future headers. This wouldn't make your script smaller, but would improve load times by caching on the client side.

An alternative suggestion would be to use a different library if you need only limited functionality (e.g. only the selectors or only effects).

A few examples

http://fx.inetcat.com/ - an effects library (3kb)

http://sizzlejs.com/ - A selectors library

There are more listed here : http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/

Going with these *might* be the solution for you *if* you don't depend on jQuery for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd just lump it. I think in this day and age it's perfectly reasonable and if you're using jQuery via a CDN, it's probably zero bandwidth overhead for both you and the visitor.

Comment: Sorry , but this is just opinion and doesn't answer the question. There could well be a good reason for keeping the page size down in this day and age still.

Comment: Revoked the downvote as you've highlighted the benefits of using the CDN. Probably worth pointing out that the benefit of CDN browser cached jQuery script would be lost if using a custom jQuery script.